# Why does go-validator have to be a pointer?

Tags: go

I saw a tutorial on internet and it created a validator as a pointer but never explained. Is there any underlying purpose of doing this?

```
// Validation contains
type Validation struct {
    validate *validator.Validate
}

// NewValidation creates a new Validation type
func NewValidation() *Validation {
    validate := validator.New()
    validate.RegisterValidation("sku", validateSKU)

    return &Validation{validate}
}
```

Comment: first, make your title correct.  it is not Go Validator it is 
go-validator

Comment: @ManjeetThakur Sorry for the inconvenience, I edited the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is returning the pointer of Validate struct with the default values. and it is type of `*validator.Validate`

```
validate := validator.New()
func New() *Validate { }
```